# Is there a way to compare what is added and what is destroyed with a terraform plan?

Tags: terraform

I am currently refactoring a terraform repository and dont want to make any changes to the existing infrastructure. Because of new modules some resources have to be destroyed and be created again. To make sure that the resources are equal I want to compare what is destroyed to what is created without manually going through the plan. Is there an easier way for this?

```
     # module.Loadbalancer.module.Listener.module.ListenerRules.aws_lb_listener_rule.listener_rule_external-listener-443_9602[0] will be created
      + resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "listener_rule_external-listener-443_9602" {
          + arn          = (known after apply)
          + id           = (known after apply)
          + listener_arn = "someListenerARN"
          + priority     = 9602
          + tags_all     = (known after apply)
    
          + action {
              + order = (known after apply)
              + type  = "redirect"
    
              + redirect {
                  + host        = "test.com"
                  + path        = "/path"
                  + port        = "#{port}"
                  + protocol    = "#{protocol}"
                  + query       = "#{query}"
                  + status_code = "HTTP_301"
                }
            }
    
          + condition {
              + host_header {
                  + values = [
                      + "test.de",
                    ]
                }
            }
          + condition {
    
              + path_pattern {
                  + values = [
                      + "/path-path",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    
  # module.Loadbalancer.module.Listener.module.ListenerRules.aws_lb_listener_rule.listener_rule_external-listener-443_9603 will be destroyed
  # (because resource uses count or for_each)
  - resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "listener_rule_external-listener-at-443_9603" {
      - arn          = "someOldARN" -> null
      - id           = "someOldID" -> null
      - listener_arn = "someListenerARN" -> null
      - priority     = 9603 -> null
      - tags         = {} -> null
      - tags_all     = {} -> null

      - action {
          - order = 1 -> null
          - type  = "redirect" -> null

          - redirect {
              - host        = "test.com" -> null
              - path        = "/path" -> null
              - port        = "#{port}" -> null
              - protocol    = "#{protocol}" -> null
              - query       = "#{query}" -> null
              - status_code = "HTTP_301" -> null
            }
        }

      - condition {
          - host_header {
              - values = [
                  - "test.de",
                ] -> null
            }
        }
      - condition {

          - path_pattern {
              - values = [
                  - "/path-path",
                ] -> null
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What would be an easier way, how do you envision that?

Comment: I'd like to use something similar to diff where i can directly compare the created and deleted resource of the same name. Problem with that is that I don't know a way to separate the deleted and created resources due to different number of attributes in every other resource.

Comment: Would you mind adding an example to the question? It does not have to be a real example, just something you see and what you would like to achieve. It's hard for me to comprehend what the requirement is.

Comment: I've adden an example. I would like to easily see potential differences without having to scroll between the two resources.

Comment: For Context, I have moved some previously static values like the host into variables and want to see if I used the new variables at the right places.

Comment: Just use your diff tool of choice, ultimately it's just some text. Something like http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/ would do it. But really there are lots of off the shelf solutions for this

Comment: @Mtero You could use Terraform Cloud if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have made the following changes in the configuration:

- `resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "listener_rule_external-listener-443_9603"` is now renamed to `resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "listener_rule_external-listener-443_9602"` -- that is, the number on the end of the name is different.
- The resource now has `count` enabled, so its first instance now has the instance key `[0]`.

By default Terraform assumes that you intend to destroy the old object and create a new one at the new address, but you can override that behavior by writing a `moved` block alongside the `resource` block:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "listener_rule_external-listener-443_9602" {
  count = 1

  # ...
}

moved {
  from = aws_lb_listener_rule.listener_rule_external-listener-443_9603
  to   = aws_lb_listener_rule.listener_rule_external-listener-443_9602[0]
}
```

This `moved` block serves as a hint to Terraform so that if it finds an object in your prior state for this module called `aws_lb_listener_rule.listener_rule_external-listener-443_9603`, it should pretend it was originally created as `aws_lb_listener_rule.listener_rule_external-listener-443_9602[0]`. This rule will have no effect if there isn't already an object in the state with the `from` address, so it's safe to include this in a module even if not all callers of the module will need it, and you can leave it in the module indefinitely after you've applied the change.

There's more information on this mechanism in the Terraform documentation section [Refactoring](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/refactoring).

With this `moved` block in place, you should see `terraform apply` just note that the address has changed, and not propose to make any changes to the object's own configuration. If you see it *also* proposing changes to the configuration then that suggests that you've changed the configuration in some other way, in which case Terraform will propose to apply that change *in addition to* rebinding the object to a new address.